# Circular dependency in a repository "on-persist" event

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a kind of business logic, that executes some events when certain objects are persisted (either updated or inserted) to the database. Those events are each a class itself, implementing a repository, resolved by DI container.

The workflow is something like that:

Service A (repository service) runs a persist command on an Entity. After persisting, actions are executed. But here comes the problem - it is very common, that the actions itself want to use the same repository to insert or update another entity of the same type, which causes a circular dependency.

The thing is, that the circular dependency is caused by a kind of recursion, but the recursion is actually needed.

A sample code would look like that:

```
public interface IOnPersistAction {
    void Execute();
}

public class ServiceA {

    private readonly List<IOnPersistAction> actions;

    public ServiceA(List<IOnPersistAction> actions) {
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    public void PersistEntity(IEntity entity) {
        /* some persisting logic */
        foreach(var action in actions) {
            action.Execute();
        }
    }
}

public class ConcreteAction : IOnPersistAction {


    public ConcreteAction(RepositoryService repositoryService) {
        /* ... */
    }

    public void Execute() {

    }

}
```

It is obvious, that this structure can not be resolved, because ConcreteActions depends on the RepositoryService (for a good reason, the class may persist another entity and then should trigger the actions again, for the other entity).

Right now I am passing the RepositoryService to the Execute method, which kind of resolves the DI problem, but IMHO it is not the right solution.

**What design pattern or any other magic should be used to resolve this kind of recursive/circular dependency?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you can describe when the recursion should stop. In other words, at some point you are triggering another recursion-loop when you shouldn't. Add that condition (filter, if, whatever) in your code. It can be in the Persist-entity-method, or in the Concrete-action itself, or some other place we are currently not seeing.

Recursion should have a [base case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition). Without this, your recursive loop wil go on forever.

Add your base-case.

Comment: The recursion itself indeed stops some time, those actions are only triggered when certain values are present on the persisted entity, and stops otherwise. The recursion itself is not a problem. The problem is the circular dependency caused by the fact that in DI, the actions must be instantiated before I know whether they will run or not. This problem I have solved right now by removing the ConcreteAction constructor dependency and passing the RepositoryService in the Execute method, but I think it is generally not a good practice to call something like `action.Execute(this)`.